# How can I append my dataframe to itself (cbind) a given number of times? in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, cbind

I am basically trying to produce a REALLY large dataset for testing purposes, and I have an example dataset with 600,000 rows.

I want to append this df to itself n times, how would I do this?

I could cbind it to itself multiple times manually, but there must be an automated way to do specify the number of times I want it to append to itself?

Comment: Take a look at `do.call`, `cbind` & `rep`. See also `purrr::map_dfc(cbind)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `[` and repeat the relevant row indices. Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:2, y = letters[11:12])
df[rep(1:nrow(df), 10), ] # or rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 10)

    x y
1   1 k
2   2 l
1.1 1 k
2.1 2 l
1.2 1 k
2.2 2 l
1.3 1 k
2.3 2 l
1.4 1 k
2.4 2 l
1.5 1 k
2.5 2 l
1.6 1 k
2.6 2 l
1.7 1 k
2.7 2 l
1.8 1 k
2.8 2 l
1.9 1 k
2.9 2 l
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `replicate` (wrapper to `sapply`) to build a list of duplicate data frames to then run `cbind` (or `rbind` for append) once at end:

```
n <- 5
df_list <- replicate(n, mydata, simplify = FALSE)

final_df <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, df_list)
head(final_df)
```

<kbd>[Online demo](https://rextester.com/MKAA33237)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

#bind by column the same df repeated n times (in this example = 3)
rep_df<-bind_cols(rep(df,3))
```

Comment: Yes. I ran the previous code with some dummy data and seemed to generate the desired output.